# Populating ContextMenuInfo for arbitrary views

Tags: android

I have list of arbitrary view(s) which on long click will display context menu, these views are not necessarily child's of ListView. With my code contextmenu is displayed but problem is when a menu item is selected under (in onContextItemSelected of Activity) MenuItem.getMenuInfo() is unset (null)

Then I tried something like below

```
class MyView{

  public MyView(Context context){
     super(context);
     setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
  }

  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menuInfo = new AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo(v,
                getPosition(v), v.getId());
        getActivity().onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
}
```

Then on Activity which is responsible for actually showing ContextMenu and handling clicks, inside **onContextItemSelected** I have MenuItem.getMenuInfo() still NULL, which is obviously not null under **onCreateContextMenu** of Activity class. My question is if I create context menus using **registerForContextMenu()** of Activity class or as per above code, in both cases how do we populate some data in MenuItem.getMenuInfo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by overriding following method in my Custom view class

```
@Override 
protected ContextMenuInfo getContextMenuInfo() {
         return null;
}
```

There you can return whatever value, such as instance of **AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo**